# обновление php внутри ветки. CentOS 7

Tags: php, centos, администрирование, yum

Везде по интернету подробно расписано как устанавливать php.
У меня вопрос такой - вот вышла новая версия php (была 7.1.6, вышла 7.1.7)
Так как сервер в продакшене - нет возможности для экспериментов.
Хочу спросить у людей - как правильно обновлять такие вещи?
У меня установлен php 7.1 из репозитария webtatic.

Время прошло и хотелось бы обновить именно php а не все подряд на сервере.
Команда yum update - обновит все.
надо как-то yum update php или что такое.

Прошу помощи - в интернете к сожалению этот вопрос обходят стороной.
Как будет наиболее правильно обновить версию php если просто вышла новая минорная?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

1. удалить предыдущие и поставить новую версию

   yum remove mod_php* php7*

   yum install php72w-fpm php72w-opcache php72w-cli php72w-gd php72w-mbstring php72w-mcrypt php72w-mysqlnd php72w-xml php72w-soap php72w-xmlrpc
2. обновить существующие

   yum update mod_php* php7*

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее правильный вариант:

1. Создать новый сервер с нуля
2. Развернуть приложение на нем
3. Прогнать тесты
4. На балансировщике переключить часть трафика на новый сервер
5. Переключить весь трафик на новый сервер
6. Удалить старый сервер

Если в любом пункте возникают проблемы, то все откатить, проанализировать проблемы и начать сначала используя результаты анализа.

Comment: ну это если прям совсем все правильно. А если ресурсы не слишком велики? Если не слишком критичны приложения?
В рамках одного сервера - не?

Comment: @progreccor так как раз и надо на таких приложениях тренироваться. И это не так дорого, как может показаться в начале. Но гарантирует вам быстрый откат в случае проблем

Comment: @progreccor подымите виртуальную машину на своём компе и поиграйтесь. Как будете готовы -- приобретайте второй сервер и переключайтесь сразу. Поставить две версии PHP на один сервер можно, но геморно и чревато граблями.

Comment: я разве говорил про то чтобы установить две версии php? речь про то как правильно обновить!